# How to create multiple repositories in Penatho

Tags: pentaho, data-integration, multiple-repositories

I would like to know how to create different (multiple) repositories in Pentaho Enterprise version.
Below are some points which I would like to add.
1. Different repositories for different users, so one user cant access the other users transformations and jobs.
2. One user cant access the DB connections of other users in different repositories.

My main concern is I want logic here is for security reasons. One user cant access or update other users created transformation.

Is this possible? Please help me on this.

Thanks for all in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly how my repos are set up. I use database repos on PostgreSQL for all my users. To create a new repo, just click the green `+` button at the top right of the Repository Connection dialog.

To keep users out of each others sandboxes, I create a different schema for each user and assign DB permissions accordingly. Note, the schema has to be created before you create the repo. Of course I'm DB superuser so I can get into all their repos.

When you create a connection for a repo, go to the advanced tab and specify that user's schema in the 'Preferred schema name' box. Note, this connection will not appear in your list of connections stored in the repo; it's in the repositories.xml file in the .kettle directory. I also created a template xml file that I can tweak give out to anyone who comes on board as a developer. That way they only see their repo in the connection dialog, but my repositories.xml has all of their repos.

You can do this with file based repos as well, but of course you'd handle permissions through the file system rather than the DB.

It's also true that repos can have multiple users. I use this feature when members of the same group need to share transforms. For example the Data Warehouse group is all in one repo, but each has their own directory; the other group has their own repo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure ,that you can create multiple instatnce of same repository , but

> i sugest you can use single repository with different user and with
>   different user level permissions

You concerns can be re-solved based on user level permission on repo

Comment: Thanks for helping.... It can possible for me that the DB connections created by one user do not visible to other users in same repo.? Please help me out of this..